# Saving user info to Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I've created a user using Firestore, but I can't save it to a struct to later get the user's first name for a label. How do I solve this?

```swift
//create the user
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in
    print(result)
    //check for errors
    if err != nil {
        //there was an error while creating user
        self.showError("Error creating user")
    }//end if
    else {
        //user was created successfully, store name, last name and email
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName, "age": age!, "imageUrl": imageUrl, "email": email, "uid": result!.user.uid]) { (error) in

            if error != nil {
                //show error message
                self.showError("Account created, but database couldn't save name")
            }//end of if
        }//end of db collection

        //save current user
        //This is where I would like to save my user to my struct

        //transition to homescreen
        self.transitionToTabBarVC()
    }//end else

}//end of create user
```

Comment: convert the struct to a class, classes are reference types. unlike structs that are value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the user's profile information like this:

```swift
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if let user = user {
  let uid = user.uid
  let email = user.email
  let photoURL = user.photoURL
  let displayName = user.displayName
}
```

If you'd like to store additional application-specific profile information (e.g. their favourite colour or anything else specific to your app), I'd recommend storing this in a collection in Firestore that is *not* named `users`, to prevent any confusion. Name it `profiles`, for example.

Then, create a `ProfileRepository` class that fetches the user's profile like this:

```swift
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct UserProfile: Codable {
  var favouriteColour: String
}

class ProfileRepository {

  func getUserProfile(completion: @escaping  (_ profile: UserProfile) -> Void) {
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
      let profileRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("profiles").document(uid)
      profileRef.getDocument { (documentSnapshot, error) in
        do {
          if let profile = try documentSnapshot?.data(as: UserProfile.self) {
            completion(profile)
          }
        }
        catch {
          print(error)
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Keep in mind that, as most Firebase APIs are asynchronous, you'll need to use a callback mechanism to return the profile to the caller. Here, I've used a closure (which I personally like a lot more than delegates).

I'm also making use of Firebase's support for Codable, so you'll have to add this line to your `Podfile`:

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
```